# Generate 128 barcode font in ssrs 2016 and visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

I am working with reports in Visual Studio 2017 and Reporting Service 2017,
and I have to use 128 barcode font in my report.
I want free way to do that.
I tried to use with IDAutomation dll but I didnt work for me.
Any one have some easy and free way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the 128 barcode font from here:

http://www.barcodelink.net/barcode-font.php

Copy the font to C:\Windows\Fonts on both the client and server. You should be able to access this in your VS instance. **Don't forget** to restart the report server.

I had to do something similar with 3 of 9 barcode. So I believe it is the same process.

Let me know if you've anymore questions.

Thanks

Gav

Comment: And then what should I write in the report? how I use it?

Comment: Hi Tehila, apologies for getting back late. So it's exactly like changing the font on any text. So create a text box, type in text or input a dataset value. Then at the top tool bar where you change the font, you should have the option to change to 128 barcode font, once of course you've install the font on both your own machine and the reporting server. Thanks Gav